# How to create an C# Web/Windows application to run Nunit test cases?

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

I'm new to Nunit. I've generated NUnit scripts from Selenium and able to execute from visual studio without any issue. Now I need to create an application (web/Windows) in C# which reads these test cases from .dll, execute the tests and displays result in C# application.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Kali

Comment: why you need to write your own one, can't you use any of existing? If you can't use any existing, what have you tried so far?

Comment: NUnit gives you a report. You just need to parse this.

Comment: @Giedrius - Yes, you are right. but we need more project specific customized UI. I've tried NUnit GUI runner.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Download](http://nunit.org/?p=download) and install NUnit 2.6.2 Package. This allows the test cases to be directly executed from Visual Studio.
2. Create a new Class Library project called "TestMyApplication" under your solution.
3. Add the NUnit reference to your test project using NuGet or directly add a reference to nunit.framework.
4. Add the namespace "using NUnit.Framework;"
5. Start writing the test methods

   ```
   namespace NUnitTests
   {
      [TestFixture]
      public class TestClass: TestContext<CountryRepository>
      {
         [Test]
         public void Testmethod()
         {
            // Arrange
            // ACT
            // Assert
         }
      }
   }
   ```
6. Right-click on the project and "Run Unit Tests".